# Ansible run task when variable contains some word

Tags: linux, ansible, devops

I have an ansible task, which get all elasticsearch roles

```
- name: Get all roles
  shell: curl -u elastic:123456789 "192.168.2.13:9200/_security/role"
  register: roles
```

and i want to execute the task below, only if roles.stdout variable contain word Uzbekistan

```
- name: register role (if doesn't exist)
  shell: curl -u elastic:123456789 "192.168.2.12:9200"
  when: roles.stdout =="Uzbekistan"
```

so how can i do this?

Comment: *roles* is a [*keyword*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). Don't use it as a variable.

Comment: Thanq Volodija!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it

Using `search`

```yaml
- name: register role (if doesn't exist)
  shell: curl -u elastic:123456789 "192.168.2.12:9200"
  when: roles.stdout is search('Uzbekistan')
```

Using `in`

```yaml
- name: register role (if doesn't exist)
  shell: curl -u elastic:123456789 "192.168.2.12:9200"
  when: "'Uzbekistan' in roles.stdout"
```

Using `find`

```yaml
- name: register role (if doesn't exist)
  shell: curl -u elastic:123456789 "192.168.2.12:9200"
  when: roles.stdout.find('Uzbekistan')
```

Comment: Thank you! i will give you a dish with a fresh plov!